# Throttling network speed for WebSockets

Tags: performance, google-chrome, websocket, performance-testing

We are doing performance testing on our WebSockets web app. As our app is used in Africa, we need to also test it on very slow connection speeds.

Chrome's network throttling feature works great for HTTP traffic (HTML, CSS, JS, etc. files), but it doesn't seem to be throttling the WebSocket traffic. It would be great if we could throttle that somehow too.

Comment: There is an open issue for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423246

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Linux, have a look on traffic shaping using "tc" command. You can also use it to slow a connection down. Doing it in network low level stack is better than doing it in server. You can also use random drops etc. with tc.

Answer (score 4):

WebSocket requests are throttlable now! https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-99/#websocket